# Какой Андройд лучше всего использовать для взаимодейсвтия с его файловой системой из хост машины

Tags: android, linux, virtualbox

Возникла задача достать видео из приватной группы в телеграме,
Поставил на виртуалбокс Android 86 , установил туда телеграм, зашел в приватную группу и загрузил в кэш видео, потом через терминал зашел в кэш телеграма и перенес от туда файлы в другую папку что бы вытащить их через фтп мост. (Дополнения для гостевой ОС почему то не встают на Андройд 86)
Может кто знает есть ли более простые способы.
Возможно какие то дистрибьютивы Андройда или еще что.

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить. А зачем ставить аж целую виртуалку да ещё и с нестандартной ос? Чем хотя бы другой пользователь не устроил?